# If $Q$ is square matrix and $Q Q^T=I$, prove that $|\text{det}\:(Q)|=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $Q$ is square matrix and $Q Q^T=I$, prove that $|\text{det}\:(Q)|=1$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do $\det Q$ and $\det Q^T$ relate?

Comment: Q^T is the transpose of Q

Comment: And what do you know about $det|Q  Q^T|$

Comment: Well, I think det|QQ^T| = 1 . Am I righ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that: det(Q) = det(${Q^T}$) ........(1)

From question

det(Q${Q^T}$) = det(I) = 1

det(Q)*det(${Q^T}$) = 1

${det(Q)^2}$ = 1 ...........(from (1))

So, det(Q) = +1 or -1

Hence |det(Q)| = 1

QED

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- From $QQ^{T}=I$, how are $Q^{-1}$ and $Q^{T}$ related. Can you relate this to orthogonal matrices?.
- Can you think about the Eigen values of orthogonal matrices?
- What is the relation between eigenvalues and determinant for a square matrix?

Answer (score -1):

$1=\text{det}\:I=\text{det}\:(QQ^T)=\text{det}\:(Q)\times\text{det}\:(Q^T)=[\text{det}\:(Q)]^2\implies \text{det}\:(Q)=\pm1$ so that $|\text{det}\:(Q)|=1$.